# Can a subspace be isomorphic to its containing vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space (infinite dimensional). Is there any $M$, a proper subspace of $V$, such that there is $T$ an isomorphism between $M$ and $V$?

Comment: Hint: Take $V=F^\infty$ and $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$. (Same as multiplication by $x$ in $F[x]$.)

Comment: Consider the vector space $\Bbb R$ over the field $\Bbb Q$, and let $\mathcal B$ be a basis for it. Then, $\mathcal B$ is an infinite set. Let $\mathcal B'$ be a proper subset such that there is a bijection $f\colon \mathcal B'\to \mathcal B$, this is always possible as $\mathcal B$ is an infinite set. Consider the $\Bbb Q$-span of $\mathcal B'$ and denote it by $\mathcal M$, extend the bijection $f$ linearly to get a  $\Bbb Q$-isomorphism from $\mathcal M$ onto $\Bbb R$. *Mimic this proof for any other infinite-dimensional vector space.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. I will write an answer here from functional analysis.
Take the space of continuously differentiable functions of order 1, on the compact interval $[0, 1]$, that is the space $\mathcal{C}^{1}([0, 1])$ and consider its subspace $$M=\{f\in \mathcal{C}^{1}([0, 1]): f(0)=0 \}.$$ Define now the differentiation mapping from $M$  to  $\mathcal{C}([0, 1])$ by $$D(f)= f'.$$ This is an isometric isomorphism between these two infinite dimensional spaces and as is known, $\mathcal{C}^{1}([0, 1])$  is a proper subspace of $\mathcal{C}([0, 1])$. Put $V= \mathcal{C}([0, 1])$ and therefore $M$ is a proper subspace of V even though they are (isometrically)isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\oplus F_{n}$, where each $F_{n}=F$ is a field and the direct sum is over the set $n=1,2,3 ,...$. Consider $A$ as a subset of $A\oplus F \cong A$.